# How to migrate vm´s from oracle virtualbox hypervisor to LXD or Docker Containers

Tags: virtualbox, intel, docker, lxd

Thinking about to run virtual maschines on LXD as LXD guests instead on virtualbox installed on this ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server:

How to migrate existing vm's? Simply export as OVA and and import them? Maybe OVA converting required?

First going to install LXD like this: https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/lxd

Then going to get existing Virtualbox vm's up and startet with LXD instead of starting them with VirtualBox.

LXD seems me more performant to this constellation because LXD is native or bare-metal hypervisor and VirtualBox ist hosted hypervisor.

Any performace comparison benchmarks to look to?

How to get existing virtualbox vms to raw format, like described here: https://stgraber.org/2012/03/04/boot...lxc-container/

On server with virtualbox are currently running two vm´s: One more ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server and one Microsoft Windows 2012 R2 server with Microsoft SQL 2014 Express for SAP Business One.

Anyone who done this and has experience with this "performance tuning" and may give me hints, tipps and tricks in advance?

DL

Comment: Bad link: https://stgraber.org/2012/03/04/boot...lxc-container/

Answer (score 0):

With LXD you can only run Linux distributions and not Windows.
The list of supported Linux distributions is 
https://us.images.linuxcontainers.org/

LXD containers have near native performance. It relates to the way that Linux Containers work.

As far as I know, there are no automated tools yet that can convert a Linux installation into a LXD container. 
Having said that, the maintainer of LXD (`stgraber`) is presenting at FOSDEM in February and will demonstrate such a tool. If you are located near Brussels, you may try to attend the presentation.

Without an automated tool, you would need to manually migrate from the VM to the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply explained hypervisors share the hardware between hosts and virtual machines. LXD shares the Linux kernel between the containers and the native programs. That is why it is more efficient and that is why you can't use it for Windows programs.